# murmur3 hashing function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, hash, pg, murmurhash

I want to use murmur3 hashing function in postgres , is there any default in postgres .
In PostgreSQL do we have any mechanism for fetching this murmur3 hash function for any UUID

I haven't go anything to try for getting murmur has for existing uuid .